# Why is my merge layout showing up twice inside LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a merge layout inside a parent LinearLayout. For some reason, the merge layout is showing up twice, one on top of the other, in the fragment when I run my app. Layout Inspector shows all the elements from the merge layout repeated below the first set, and all directly under the LinearLayout. Even weirder is that the repeated elements have the same id's.

Parent layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include layout="@layout/child_layout" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Child layout:

```
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="title" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="stuff" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/positiveButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/negativeButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</merge>
```

Fragment code:

```
    private var _binding: ParentBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private var _contentBinding: ChildBinding? = null
    private val contentBinding get() = _contentBinding!!

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        _binding = ParentBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        _contentBinding = ChildBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, binding.root)
        return binding.root
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What's Happening?**

You are inflating the parent layout 2 times in `onCreateView`.

**Solution**

Replace this: `_contentBinding = ChildBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, binding.root)`

With this: `_contentBinding = ChildBinding.bind(binding.root)`